# Treeview frame on canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, tkinter-canvas

[image]This code has 2 problems:
1. I can't get the treeview frame to fill the entire canvas (vertically)
2. I don't want the first column to be displayed
How can I fix these?

```
import os

import time
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from tkinter.constants import TRUE

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFont
    import ttk

    from Tkconstants import CENTER, LEFT, N, E, W, S
    from Tkinter import StringVar
except ImportError: # py3k
    import tkinter as Tkinter
    import tkinter.font as tkFont
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

    from tkinter.constants import CENTER, LEFT, N, E, W, S
    from tkinter import StringVar

GRID_BORDER_WIDTH = "1"

def populate_treeview(frame, my_column_headers, my_list):

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Calibri', 11)) # Modify the font of the body
    style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 13,'bold')) # Modify the font of the headings
    style.layout("mystyle.Treeview", [('mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]) # Remove the borders

    tree=ttk.Treeview(frame, style="mystyle.Treeview") # create the widget

    tree["columns"]=my_column_headers
    for i in range (0,26):
        tree.column(my_column_headers[i], width=50, minwidth=20, stretch=Tkinter.YES)

    for i in range (0,26):
        tree.heading(my_column_headers[i] ,text=my_column_headers[i], anchor=Tkinter.W)

    PARENT="" # top level
    i = 0
    for item in my_list:
        #print ("item: " + str(item)) 
        tree.insert(PARENT, i, i, text=str(i), values=(item))
        i += 1

    tree.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=TRUE)

def OnFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def OnCanvasConfigure(self, event):
    width = 0
    for child in self.sensorsStatsFrame.grid_slaves():
        width += child.winfo_reqwidth()

    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.canvas_frame, width=width, height=event.height)

# main ########################################################################
def main():

    print ("[DEBUG]***  Display Test***)\n");

    # Data
    item_column_headers =  ["a", "b", "c", "d","e", "f", "g", "h","i", "j", "k", "l","m", "n", "o", "p","q", "r", "s", "t", "u","v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    item_list = []
    for row_number in range (0,50):
        row = []
        for alpha in item_column_headers:
            row.append (str(row_number) + alpha)
        item_list.append(row)

    print (item_list)

    ## GUI ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    root = Tkinter.Tk()

    canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, borderwidth=6, background="#222222" )

    frame = Tkinter.Frame(canvas, background="#ff0000", borderwidth = 5)
    frame.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP, expand=1, fill=Tkinter.BOTH)
    canvas.create_window((0,0), window = frame, anchor="nw", tags="my_tag")
    canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda event,  root=root:OnCanvasConfigure(root))

    verticalScrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=verticalScrollbar.set)
    verticalScrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=0)

    horizontalScrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
    canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=horizontalScrollbar.set)
    horizontalScrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", expand=0)

    canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

    frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: OnFrameConfigure(canvas))
    #frame.bind("<Configure>", OnFrameConfigure)

    populate_treeview(frame, item_column_headers, item_list) 

    root.geometry("1000x600")
    root.wm_title("Display Test")

    root.mainloop()

    print ("\n*** Done " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "  - Display Test ***");

# main ###############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
    main()
```

Here is code with fixes suggested by @BryanOakley

```
import os

import time
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from tkinter.constants import TRUE

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFont
    import ttk

    from Tkconstants import CENTER, LEFT, N, E, W, S
    from Tkinter import StringVar
except ImportError: # py3k
    import tkinter as Tkinter
    import tkinter.font as tkFont
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

    from tkinter.constants import CENTER, LEFT, N, E, W, S
    from tkinter import StringVar

GRID_BORDER_WIDTH = "1"

def populate_treeview(frame, my_column_headers, my_list):

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Calibri', 11)) # Modify the font of the body
    style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 13,'bold')) # Modify the font of the headings
    style.layout("mystyle.Treeview", [('mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]) # Remove the borders

    tree=ttk.Treeview(frame, style="mystyle.Treeview") # create the widget

    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(tree, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
    vsb.configure(command=tree.yview)
    vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(tree, orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)
    hsb.configure(command=tree.xview)
    hsb.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
    tree.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

    tree["columns"]=my_column_headers

    for i in range (0,26):
        tree.column(my_column_headers[i], width=50, minwidth=20, stretch=Tkinter.YES)

    for i in range (0,26):
        tree.heading(my_column_headers[i] ,text=my_column_headers[i], anchor=Tkinter.W)

    PARENT="" # top level
    i = 0
    for item in my_list:
        #print ("item: " + str(item)) 
        tree.insert(PARENT, i, i, text=str(i), values=(item))
        i += 1

    tree["show"] = ["headings"]        
    tree.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP, fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=TRUE)

# main ########################################################################
def main():

    print ("[DEBUG]***  Display Test***)\n");

    # Data
    item_column_headers =  ["a", "b", "c", "d","e", "f", "g", "h","i", "j", "k", "l","m", "n", "o", "p","q", "r", "s", "t", "u","v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    item_list = []
    for row_number in range (0,50):
        row = []
        for alpha in item_column_headers:
            row.append (str(row_number) + alpha)
        item_list.append(row)

    ## GUI ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    root = Tkinter.Tk()

    frame = Tkinter.Frame(root, background="#ff0000", borderwidth = 5)
    frame.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP, expand=1, fill=Tkinter.BOTH)

    populate_treeview(frame, item_column_headers, item_list) 

    root.geometry("1000x600")
    root.wm_title("Display Test")

    root.mainloop()

    print ("\n*** Done " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "  - Display Test ***");

# main ###############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
    main()
```

Comment: Try to create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) code that shows the problem you're having. To make problems easier to understand.

Comment: This is a test program I made separate from the actual application I am writing. While it may not be minimal, since I'm not sure where the problem is, it is complete and verifiable. Simply copying/pasting this into a file will allow it to be executed and thus see the problem.

Comment: Are you aware of this bug in the code you posted? `TypeError: OnCanvasConfigure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I was aware of it. I have tried many things. That error is just the last thing that I tried. And I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you using `self` in some places? None of this code is defined as part of a class. That makes the code very confusing and hard to understand. I think the code you posted is too broken for us to address the question you're asking.

Comment: Are you aware that the treeview natively supports scrolling? Placing it in a canvas so that you can scroll it via the canvas likely isn't going to work as well as directly scrolling the tree

Comment: I was not aware that treeview supports scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't get the treeview frame to fill the entire canvas (vertically)

The problem with the tree not filling the canvas is because it's in a frame, and the frame doesn't fill the canvas. It looks like you're attempting to address that in your `OnCanvasConfigure` method, but there are many bugs preventing it from working.

First, you have a loop that iterates over `self.sensorsStatsFrame.grid_slaves()`, but you haven't defined `self` and there's no widget named `sensorsStatsFrame`, so this function will fail before it gets a chance to change the height of the frame. Because this code throws an error, no subsequent code in the function will run.

Next, you try to call `self.canvas.configure`, but again there is no `self` and no `self.canvas`, so that statement will fail. You also use `self.canvas_frame`, but again, that doesn't exist so the code will fail.

If you fix all of those problems, the code should allow the frame to be configured to be the same width and height as the canvas, solving the first problem you're asking about.

> I don't want the first column to be displayed

The `treeview` attribute `show` lets you define what parts of the tree to show. You assign it a list that contains `"tree"` and/or `"headings"`. You don't want to see the first column, which is represented by `"tree"`. Thus, to hide that value you want to pass `"headings"` as the only value in the list used for the `show` attribute.

```
tree["show"] = ["headings"]
```

Comment: Thanks. The "show" fixes the first column problem easily. I'll work on the other one...

Comment: Removing the canvas and using treeview scrolling was the solution. I've added fixed code to the original question. Maybe add your comment about the treeview scrolling and that's a complete answer.

Comment: @AlLelopath I think all you've done is add confusion. This answer addresses the question that was asked. You didn't ask about scrolling a treeview, you asked about how to make the treeview the same size as the canvas. Those are two completely different questions.

Comment: I agree that the question was how to expand a `treeview` frame to the `canvas`. The question was asked in ignorance. So I can 1. Accept your answer as is. 2. Delete the question. I prefer 1, so unless you protest, I will do that.